# Error generating Google Chart using local CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, csv, google-visualization

I have an HTML file where I am uploading a local CSV file and once it has been uploaded I want to use the Google Charts API to generate a chart from that data however I am currently get this error

```
script.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined
```

this points to the line in the JavaScript file

```
  var dataDraw = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```

This is the index.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CSV to chart</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="inputs" class="clearfix">
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
      </div>
      <hr />
      <output id="list">
      </output>
      <hr />
      <table id="contents" style="width:100%; height:400px;" border>
      </table>
      <div id="chart"></div>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/src/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the Javascript file

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#files').bind('change', handleFileSelect);

});

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; 
  var file = files[0];
  printTable(file);
}

function printTable(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = function(event){
    var csv = event.target.result;
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);


    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});    

    var dataDraw = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataDraw);
    view.setColumns([0,1]);


    var options = {
      title: "CSV Chart",
      hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
      vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(view, options);

    console.log("array of data " + data)
    var html = '';  
    for(var row in data) {
      html += '<tr>\r\n';
      for(var item in data[row]) {
        html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
      }
      html += '</tr>\r\n';
    }
    $('#contents').html(html);
  };
  reader.onerror = function(){ alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName); };
}
```

This is the CSV I am uploading.

```
Temp,Number
69,1
23.5,2
2.3,3
```

I am having trouble generating a chart from a local CSV file that I am uploading to use with the Google Charts API. I am quite new to using Google Charts so can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple issues here...

first, the following `load` statement is incorrect, it is for the old version of google charts.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

it should be replaced with...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code) for more info...

---

next, you need to wait until the `load` statement has finished,
before using any google chart components,
there are a few ways...

1) you can use the promise the `load` statement returns.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  // place chart code here
});
```

2) use the `callback` property of the `load` statement.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: function () {
    // place chart code here
  }
});
```

3) use the `setOnLoadCallback` callback method.

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  // place chart code here
});
```

obviously, you can replace any of the above anonymous functions with a named one of your own, e.g.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: drawChart
});
```

---

note: `arrayToDataTable` is a *static* method, the `new` keyword is not needed...

```
var dataDraw = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```

---

**EDIT**

if you receive the error...

`Data for column(s) axis #0 cannot be of type String`

this means the values for the y-axis columns are formatted as strings and not numbers. (columns > 0)

to correct the issue, add a calculated column to the view,
and parse the value as float.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataDraw);
view.setColumns([0, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return parseFloat(dt.getValue(row, 1));
  },
  type: 'number',
  label: dataDraw.getColumnLabel(1)
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I implemented the solution above but now I am getting an error with ColumnLabel.  `script.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.getColumnLabel is not a function`

Comment: `script.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.getColumnLabel is not a function` This points to the code in the JavaScript file, `hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max}` and when I remove these 2 lines it causes the error,  `Data for column(s) axis #0 cannot be of type String`

Comment: from the code in the question, the data table variable appears to be named --> `dataDraw` -- not `data` -- so --> `dataDraw.getColumnLabel`

Comment: Grateful for the help, I am still getting the error `Data for column(s) axis #0 cannot be of type String` after making the change?